# How To get this Count Query in C#.net

Tags: c#, .net

the below coding getting execute but the value was not printing in screen

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (CheckBox1.Checked)
        {

        string OIMSquery = "SELECT COUNT(name) AS PolicySold FROM TestDate WHERE name='divi'";
        SqlCommand OIMScmd = new SqlCommand(OIMSquery, OIMS_01);
        OIMS_01.Open();
        OIMScmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        OIMS_01.Close();      

        }       
   }
```

Comment: Did you debug your code? Do you have any error or exception?

Comment: I don't see you displaying anything here. Of course it's not on the screen then.

Answer (score 3):

You should call [ExectueScaler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) like

```
int count = (int) OIMScmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

[ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx)

> Executes the query, and returns the first column of the first row in
>   the result set returned by the query. Additional columns or rows are
>   ignored.

Comment: @downvoter, I would be glad if the mistake in the answer can be identified ?

Comment: I didn't downvote (and certainly wouldn't over such a tiny nitpick), but as a point of style I wouldn't mix `int` and `Int32`. Decide which you prefer to use, and be consistent.

Comment: @JonSkeet, I had `Int32` in the start , but then modified just the first one , forgot to modify the other, Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 1):

use `ExecuteScalar()` to fetch single value

```
string OIMSquery = "SELECT COUNT(name) AS PolicySold FROM TestDate WHERE name='divi'";
SqlCommand OIMScmd = new SqlCommand(OIMSquery, OIMS_01);
OIMS_01.Open();
int _result = Convert.ToInt32(OIMScmd.ExecuteScalar());
OIMS_01.Close();
```

- [ExecuteScalar()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You've got a query. Therefore this call is inappropriate:

```
OIMScmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Instead, you should be using [`ExecuteScalar()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx):

```
int count = (int) OIMScmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

(It's possible that it'll return a `long` rather than an `int` - I'm not sure offhand.)

Additionally, you should use a `using` statement for the `SqlCommand` and create a new connection for each operation:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(...))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
    {
        int count = (int) command.ExecuteScalar();
        // Now use the count
    }
}
```

It's also not clear what kind of app this is - if it's in a local GUI (WinForms or WPF) you should *not* be performing database access on the UI thread. The UI will be frozen while the database access occurs. (If this is in a web application, it's even more important that you create a new database connection each time... you don't want two separate requests trying to use the same connection at the same time.)

Comment: _Hmm_, Jon, using `using` with both `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` is a better way? Why not enough using it with only `SqlConnection` ?

Comment: @SonerGönül: Yes, that *could* work - but I would generally prefer to dispose of both. More of a style preference than anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Use `SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()` instead of `ExecuteNonQuery()` which returns nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use: [ExecuteScalar()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx)

> Executes the query, and returns the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query. Additional columns or rows are ignored.

```
int result = Convert.ToInt32(OIMScmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

Instead of

```
OIMScmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) method;

> Executes the query, and returns the first column of the first row in
>   the result set returned by the query. Additional columns or rows are
>   ignored.

```
int i = (int)OIMScmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Since this method returns `object`, you should implicity convert it to `int`.

```
 using (SqlConnection OIMS_01 = new SqlConnection(connString))
 {
      SqlCommand OIMScmd = new SqlCommand(OIMSquery, OIMS_01);
      try
      {
          OIMS_01.Open();
          int i = (int)OIMScmd.ExecuteScalar();
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try, `OIMScmd.ExecuteReader();` method which returns the object of `SqlDataReader` class then read the value from it.

OR

use, `Convert.ToInt32(OIMScmd.ExecuteScalar())` and then print the value.